# FineUploader : Delete uploaded chunk files when i click cancel

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using fineuploader to upload large size files to the server as chunks.

However, when i click "cancel" button while uploading is in progress it just cancels the uploading process leaving the partially loaded chunk files and folder. How to delete these files when i click cancel.

I tried onCancel event but i don't get the desired result.

Below is my code:

```
var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
    template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
    request: {
        endpoint: "php-traditional-server-master/endpoint.php"
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: "php-traditional-server-master/endpoint.php"
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true,
        concurrent: {
            enabled: false
        },
        success: {
           endpoint: "php-traditional-server-master/endpoint.php?done"
        }
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true,
        showButton: true
    },
    callbacks: {
        onCancel: function(id, name) {
            FineUploader.cancel(id);
       }

    },
    thumbnails: {
        placeholders: {
            waitingPath: 'client/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
            notAvailablePath: 'client/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
        }
    },
    cors: {
        expected: true
    },
    maxConnections : 1,
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true
});

qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
    manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
});
```

Kindly advise me on the above.

Thanks.

Comment: Just send a request to your server asking it to cleanup any chunks for a file, given the file uuid.

Comment: How and where should i send the request? Inside the callbacks:onCancel ? I'm new to this, appreciate any help.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable place

Comment: Is there a dedicated function by default which i can call inside the onCancel, or i had to send it through ajax and write my own code to delete the files.

Comment: You'll need to write your own code.